# unknown command 'MIGRATE', with args beginning with

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cli

I have an existing **source** redis instance running on redis version 6.0.5 cache.m6g.large

I have a **target** redis instance running on redis version 7.1.0

**I want to migrate keys from the source to the target**. using the redis-cli command https://redis.io/commands/migrate/

```
redis-cli --version
redis-cli 6.0.16
```

However im receiving the following error:

> (error) ERR unknown command 'MIGRATE', with args beginning with:
> 'redis.redacted.com' '6379' '' '0' '5000' 'KEYS'
> 'namespace:data-api,key:jsonapi:[http://data.api.redacted.com/redacted/redacted?end_d'](http://data.api.redacted.com/redacted/redacted?end_d%27)

```
source_host=""
source_port=6379
source_db=0

target_host=""
target_port=6379
target_db=0

redis-cli -h $source_host -p $source_port -n $source_db --scan | xargs redis-cli -h $target_host -p $target_port -n $target_db MIGRATE $source_host $source_port "" 0 5000 KEYS
```

Even if i try individually without the script

```
MIGRATE redis.acme.com 6379 "" 0 5000 KEYS "some_key"
```

> (error) ERR unknown command 'MIGRATE', with args beginning with:
> 'redis.acme.com' '6379' '' '0' '5000' 'KEYS' 'some_key'**strong
> text**

Whaat am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check your redis.conf, MIGRATE might be disabled/renamed by your administrator.

Comment: Yes this is mostly the culprit, as i can't even access the redis.conf CONFIG GET *
(error) ERR unknown command 'CONFIG', with args beginning with: 'GET' '*'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS's elasticache redis has made the `migrate` command unavialable.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/SupportedCommands.html